# I don't understand why I receive 403 forbidden?

Tags: laravel

I want to create a new user with this function in my controller:

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    $this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $user = new User();
    $user->role_id = 2;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    if ($user->save())
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'services' => $user
        ]);
    else
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry, user could not be added'
        ], 500);
}
```

but when I use postman for try to make new user I get 403 forbidden.
I am really confused.

Comment: Post StorreUser request file

Answer (score 0):

When using postman make sure you authenticate first. You will get back a bearer token which you put in the auth header of the store request to make an authenticated call. There are presets in postman for authentication. Select bearer and enter your token and your store call should pass as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, is my fault.
I forget to change in my request authorization true.
sorry for this

Comment: You could as well remove entirely the authorize method and the effect would be the same as setting it to true